# How to get rid of the leading space at the beginning of STDOUT?

Tags: bash, shell

Code:

```
find . -type f -exec file -b -- {} \; | sort | uniq -c | \
  sort -r -n | awk '{$1=""; print $0;}'
```

Output:

```
 GIF image data, version 89a, 57 x 68
 GIF image data, version 89a, 8 x 8
 GIF image data, version 89a, 17 x 11
 PNG image data, 128 x 128, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
 JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.02, aspect ratio, density 100x100, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 100x457, frames 3
 JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=0], baseline, precision 8, 510x300, frames 3
 HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
 GIF image data, version 89a, 960 x 4
 GIF image data, version 89a, 46 x 42
 GIF image data, version 89a, 100 x 100
 Composite Document File V2 Document, Cannot read section info
 ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Desired output:

```
GIF image data, version 89a, 57 x 68
GIF image data, version 89a, 8 x 8
GIF image data, version 89a, 17 x 11
PNG image data, 128 x 128, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.02, aspect ratio, density 100x100, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 100x457, frames 3
JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=0], baseline, precision 8, 510x300, frames 3
HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
GIF image data, version 89a, 960 x 4
GIF image data, version 89a, 46 x 42
GIF image data, version 89a, 100 x 100
Composite Document File V2 Document, Cannot read section info
ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Probably fairly easy, but I can't wrap my head around it -- how to remove the first leading space.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sub()` to remove the initial space.

```
find . -type f -exec file -b -- {} \; | sort | uniq -c | sort -r -n | awk '{$1=""; sub("^ ", ""); print $0;}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
find . -type f -exec file -b -- {} \; | sort | uniq -c | sort -r -n | awk '{$1=""; print $0;}' | sed 's/ //'
```

Comment: awk followed by sed? Surely you jest... :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can replace `awk` with `sed` in this context

```
 ... | sort -nr | sed -E 's/ *[0-9]+ //'
```

removes the leading numbers (counts) with surrounding spaces.

Comment: Correct in most cases.  But if there were a million or more of one file type,  the `sed` code the `'s/ +` should be `'s/ *`, since `uniq -c` would then output *0* leading spaces.

Comment: good point.  I didn't know.  fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Method using `sed` at the end, (instead of `awk`):

```
find . -type f -exec file -b -- {} \; | sort | uniq -c | \
  sort -r -n | sed -E 's/^ *[0-9]+ //'
```

Note: Any code must allow for the output of `uniq -c` being [*right justified*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_alignment) -- `uniq -c` prints *0-6* leading spaces, depending on the number of unique items.  Example:

```
for f in 1 10 1000 100000 1000000 10000000 ; do yes "$f" | head -$f ; done | uniq -c
      1 1
     10 10
   1000 1000
 100000 100000
1000000 1000000
10000000 10000000
```